Laravel9 Spatie QueryBuilder in Job queue
I have a Job which runs in queue. There is a Spatie/QueryBuilder which should filter data through the filter which came with the request. I am sure the filter is in the queue as array and I also can log the filter inside the job. The job then call this code which I found on Github https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder/discussions/777
    $request = app(QueryBuilderRequest::class)->merge(['filter' => $this->filter]);

    Log::info($request->get('filter'));  // This is array('filter' => array('id' => 10))

    return QueryBuilder::for(Customer::class, $request)
        ->where('id', '<', 20)
        ->toBase()
        ->orderByDesc('id');

The condition is like filter[id]=10 but the result returns all ids < 20. How to set up the filter to the request properly to force QueryBuilder to use it. Thanks a lot

Finaly I found out what was the problem. I forgot to add allowdFilters() to the QueryBuilder
$request = new QueryBuilderRequest(['filter' => $this->filter]);

return QueryBuilder::for(Customer::class, $request)
    ->allowedFilters(..........)  // This was the problem
    ->toBase()
    ->orderByDesc('id');

